# Как сделать «динамический» padding или как избавиться от обёртки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, контейнеры

Есть вот такая вёрстка: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/Drovosek/pen/RYXqKd)

```
<body>
  <!-- 1 -->

<div class="main__content white">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2 -->

<div class="main__content black">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 3 -->

<div class="main__content white">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 4 -->

<div class="main__content black">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

///

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.main__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;  
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

В ней в body есть контейнеры для контента и в них еще одни контейнеры в которых находится сам контент.

```
<body>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- контент -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- контент -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- контент -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Блоку container я задаю определенный max-width и margin: auto, чтобы всё было по центру.

**Вопросы:**

1/ Влияет ли вложенность на что-то, кроме количества кода? Ну типо для поисковых машин, для СЕО это насколько плохо? Например, если я сделаю так:

```
<body>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="container3">
                    <div class="container4">
                        <!-- контент -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="container3">
                    <div class="container4">
                        <!-- контент -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="container3">
                    <div class="container4">
                        <!-- контент -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

2. Можно ли избежать блока container в первом примере и поместить весь контент в блок main__contant, но при этом чтобы результат был как с блоком container, т.е. контент так же оставался по центру и не растягивался? Типо чтобы были динамические padding'и
   (Вот тот же пример только без container, с padding'ами и контент естественно теперь растягивается: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/Drovosek/pen/RYXeWL)

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет.
2. Аналогично, использовать `margin: 0 auto;` для `main__content`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.main__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;  
  
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1 -->

<div class="main__content white">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur
    laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
</div>

<!-- 2 -->

<div class="main__content black">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur
    laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
</div>

<!-- 3 -->

<div class="main__content white">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur
    laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
</div>

<!-- 4 -->

<div class="main__content black">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt quasi placeat ratione voluptas earum quia ipsa sint sequi atque!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores incidunt, quibusdam corrupti exercitationem maiores illo ut adipisci et doloremque nemo autem ducimus tenetur esse quidem? Distinctio et facilis sed eveniet fugiat eligendi, consequatur
    laudantium, aspernatur quasi reprehenderit obcaecati, placeat beatae.</p>
</div>
```

---

Тогда такой вариант:

```css
.main_content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.max_width {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* как box-sizing: padding-box; только работает нормально. */
  max-width: calc(250px - 40px); /* аналогично */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ddd; /* Так, для визуализации */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.max_width img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_content">
  <div class="max_width">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut fringilla ex.
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50">
     Vestibulum ipsum erat, lobortis eget velit eu, pharetra convallis neque.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin: 0 auto; не поможет, т.к. черный фон теперь имеет не хилые белые полосы по бокам, а надо чтобы фон был на всю ширину окна.

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, изменил ответ.

Comment: спасибо за ответ.
Получается без контейнера/wrapper'а внутри main__content не обойтись (чтобы отцентрировать контент и сделать фон по ширине)?
Кстати padding-box только в Firefox работает: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, можно использовать для main'а `box-shadow: 1000px 0 0 0 #000, -1000px 0 0 0 #000;` или "поиграться" с псевдо-элементами, но это не очень. По поводу padding-box в курсе, сижу на мозиле, когда-то использовал его, пока не понял, что он нигде не работает (а зря).

Answer (score 0):

На [тостере](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=1279912#answers_list_answer) предложили вариант, как сделать "динамический" padding:

```
padding: 100px calc(50% - 250px);
```

Мне такой вариант подходит.

Comment: Подходит то конечно подходит, вот только нужно ли оно? Подумайте о потомках которые это будут читать и поддерживать ... это не так очевидно как вложенность, а попробуйте теперь внутри этого блока спозиционировать абсолютно элемент у края контентной области ... `left: calc(50% - 250px)`? А если потом будет решено сделать этот блок "адаптивным"? Плохое решение, да, возможно это преждевременная оптимизация, что тоже не особо хорошо, но все же ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ну адаптивность буду делать как обычно с помощью медиа-запросов. На определенной ширине я просто изменю вычитаемое число в `calc(50% - 250px)` на меньшее, чем было `calc(50% - 190px)` и т.д.